# When to use session_start()?

Tags: php, session

I've been going through some `$_SESSION` examples and I'm a little confused, should i use `session_start()` every time before I access or set `$_SESSION['variable']` or should I only use `session_start()` once per page or just once the user has successfully logged in?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use it once per page, at the very top, before you plan to use any $_SESSION variables

Comment: Just to add to that, the reason it needs to be at the top of the page, is because it makes changes to the page headers.

Answer (score 2):

You should always use `session_start()` once at the `First Line` of your PHP page if you want to access all session in `$_SESSION`

Comment: does not have to be the first line, just before the use of sessions

Comment: unless you store objects in your session and need to load the class definitions before starting the session

Comment: that's only a personal preference, nothing to do with making it work. A lot of web page incorrectly say it must be the first line in a php file, which is just wrong, and unfortunately spread all over the web.

Comment: @Dranon most time people forget ... and its cleaner at the top of the pace you are sure no output is sent

Comment: again that's just personal preference, and shouldn't be spread as some golden rule.

Comment: Its not a rule its best practice ... the only rule is you need it before any output is set

Comment: i don't agree its even best practice - says who? and more to the point why?